# How to animate/resize shape of circle dynamically in android?

Tags: android

I have to draw circle on canvas whose shape will be changing continuously as diameter length is changed. (Note, Diameter length is modified based on the intent data). Can we show smooth transition of same shape like from larger size to smaller size)

My current circle code looks like below,  (This is inside onCreate)

```
bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap((int) getWindowManager()
            .getDefaultDisplay().getWidth(), (int) getWindowManager()
            .getDefaultDisplay().getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);

        drawingImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
     // Draw Circle
        canvas.drawCircle(50, 50, 20, paint); // circle example
```

I am using ImageView. How can I change the size of same circle  dynamically. There is receiver like below

```
registerReceiver( ) 
  onReceive(Context c,Intent i){
//   Based on data , modify the drawn Circle
}
```

OnReceive would receive intent and based on data, we need to keep circle shape changing.  When I put drawCircle code inside onReceive, it's not rendering the circle too.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I would rather use a SurfaceView instead of an ImageView + Bitmap. A possible solution could look like this:

```
SurfaceHolder mHolder = mSurfaceView.getHolder();

Canvas canvas = mHolder.lockCanvas();
yourDrawCircleMethod(canvas);
canvas.unlockCanvasAndPost();
```

Note that you should also implement a SurfaceHolder.Callback to get notified about the SurfaceViews state.